# Crop and overlay a 2x2 image onto a 4x4 grid without column/row repeat

Tags: html, image, css, background-image, crop

I have a JPEG image from an OS X Photo Booth like this:

```
GR
BM
```

With the help of CSS3, I'd like to use this image on the outside of my HTML5 `article` element, like this:

```
 GR 
BaaM
GaaR
 BM
```

Or like this:

```
 GR 
GaaR
BaaM
 BM
```

Or even this:

```
 RG 
BaaM
GaaR
 MB
```

Or as you see fit on all sides, but ***without having any rows or columns where the same part of the image is repeated*** (also, as above, must have each part shown the same number of times overall), e.g., ***not*** like this:

```
GRGR
BaaM
GaaR
BMBM
```

What's the best way to do something like this with CSS3?

Comment: Are you looking for something like `background-size: 4px 4px` to artificially increase the size of it or `image-rendering: crisp-edges` to make sure, it isn't interpolated?

Comment: @MattDiMu, no, it's one of those "Green/Red/Blue/Monochrome" filter photos (where your photo appears 4 times in the original image); I want to show the individual parts on different sides of my main content.

Answer (score 1):

I am using a base div to display your image. this div needs to have the same ratio that your div.

Then, I am placing 4 copies of the image, scaled 50%, in different places of the div.

This gives your expected result around the borders, but the images colapse in the inner part of the div (see snippet).

Now, just place an aditional background in the center of the div to cover it, and you are done (hover on the snippet to see the result)

```css
div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/300), url(http://lorempixel.com/400/300), url(http://lorempixel.com/400/300), url(http://lorempixel.com/400/300);
  background-size: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0% 50%, 100% 50%, 50% 0%, 50% 100%;
}

div:hover {
  background-image: linear-gradient(white, white), url(http://lorempixel.com/400/300), url(http://lorempixel.com/400/300), url(http://lorempixel.com/400/300), url(http://lorempixel.com/400/300);
  background-position: 50% 50%, 0% 50%, 100% 50%, 50% 0%, 50% 100%;
  
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Another idea, with more markup, but a single background image

```css
.main {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/300);
  background-size: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-position: 50% 0%;
  position: relative;
}



.main:before, .main:after {
  content: "";  
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
  left: 0px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, white 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, white 75%);
}
.main:before {
  top: 0px;  
}

.main:after {
  bottom: 0px;  
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  left: 25%;
  top: 25%;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="main"><div class="inner"></div></div>
```

Comment: +1, this does seem to be as per the spec!  Do you know if this is supported everywhere, or whether there'll be some issues somewhere?  Also, I prefer that it's either supported in full, or not supported at all -- is there a way for all of the above to fit into a single `background` property?

Comment: I don't have time now, I will post another answer using a single background on the div tomorrow

Comment: heh, your thing has stopped working, and i think your choice of the background image is to blame! :p

Comment: Posted another answer with a single background image (but more additional layout). My first example is still working for me .... what is the problem that you see ?

Comment: it wasn't working at some point yesterday, because the whole host with the external image was down!  thanks for another answer!  you should have added it as a new one, for double the points for double the work! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Can it help?

```css
.content {
  background-color: white;
}

.wrapper {
  padding: 30px;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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)
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, this is the naive solution which is specifically listed as not acceptable -- a 2x2 image will be repeated twice in all outlying columns and rows of a 4x4 matrix.

Comment: Sorry for this naive solution, I can't fully understand your description about the problem. If you can post a image rather then GRBM for the demo, it would be better.

Comment: Checkout the other solution for a sample of what was required; if it didn't work for you before, try again -- vals' external image was down when you posted your comment above, it now appears to be back up.